# Menu items dissappear on rollover, Joomla 3

Tags: joomla3.0, warp, yoothemes

Something strange is happening: 
When I roll over [the links](http://www.top1percentclub.com/gail2015/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=7&Itemid=101) they start disappearing

As far as I can tell, it dosen't happen on [sub menu pages](http://www.top1percentclub.com/gail2015/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=33&Itemid=240)

Comment: I had a similar issue once, and it turned out that I had included jQuery twice. I just had quick look at your site and it does not appear to be the issue, but I bet you it is related to JavaScript and binding something to roll-over event.

Comment: I've decided to reinstall...